# Remove char at beginning of line, but start at line 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, regexp-replace

i am creating a .csv-file with nodejs.
The content of the file is from several arrays.

I am replacing `,` with `;` so .csv-format works correctly.

Now I have a little problem: Starting at line 2 of my CSV-file I have semicolons at the beginning of each line.

Here is an example:

```
14-07-2020;intLAMi_IgnRate1;intLAMi_IgnRate2
;22:00:00;59.020397;48.343338;51.309185
```

Now, because i needed to replace the `,` im using the npm package `replace-in-file` with the following code:

```
const replace = require('replace-in-file')
const options = {
      files: f,
      from: [/,/g, /^;/g],
      to: [';', ' ']
    }

replace(options)
    .then(() => {
        resolve(true)
    })
```

My Problem is, I'm not very comfortable with regexp.

The above code replaces all `,` but does seems like the regexp `/^;/g` does not work

Does somebody have an idea why my code does not work?

Comment: hi Florian! Did you try using the standard javascript `replaceAll` function? it's a fairly simple string manipulation, i'm not sure you need to worry about regular expressions in that case `replaceAll(";", ",");` if you do want to use regular expressions after all, make sure to check your expression with an editor, such as this: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @nurnachman `replaceAll` is very new, most browsers don't have it yet.

Comment: It's also not in node.js

Comment: @Barmar note taken, so maybe use `replace(/,/g, ";")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^;/g` search for a semicolon at the beginning of the file because of `^` (some software split the strings line by line, so in that case ^ refers to the start of the line, thus the confusion).

Try with

```
const options = {
   files: f,
   from: [/,/g, /\n;/g],
   to: [';', "\n"]
}
```

If you read the whole file as a string, you could also use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function:

```
fileContent.replace(/,/gi, ';').replace(/\n;/gi, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^;/gm` should work for semi-colon leading lines.

> When the multiline (m) flag is enabled, beginning and end anchors (^ and $) will match the start and end of a line, instead of the start and end of the whole string.

> Global search (g), retains the index of the last match, allowing subsequent searches to start from the end of the previous match. Without the global flag, subsequent searches will return the same match.

Let me introduce you to your new best friend when it comes to regex. https://regexr.com.